# Angular 2 – No data afte api call

Tags: api, rest, angular

I am playing around with angular 2 and the heroes tutorial. The Problem is that I always get an empty object no matter which api I call.

Here is the code:

app.compomnent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit }         from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

// Add the RxJS Observable operators we need in this app.
import './rxjs-operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>Test</h1>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  private error: any;

  ngOnInit() {

    var request = this.http.get('http://date.jsontest.com');

    console.log("Request: " + request);
    console.log("Map: " + request.map(res => res));

    console.log("Complete: " + this.http.get('http://date.jsontest.com')
        .map(res => res.json())
        .catch(this.error));
  }
}
```

main.ts:

```
// The usual bootstrapping imports
import { bootstrap }      from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS
]);
```

The result in my console:

[image]

Comment: Why do you think this is an empty object? If you log it by itself, you can inspect the contents of the object: `console.log(request.map(result => res));`

Comment: @Sjoerd Okay, but how can I get the data of `http://date.jsontest.com`. The Object just looks like `Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}` And also within the Object I can't find the supposed data of `http://date.jsontest.com`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `Observable` doesn't do anything until you subscribe to it because they are lazy

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('http://date.jsontest.com')
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(
           data => this.data = data,
           () => console.log('done'),
           err => this.error(err));
  }
```